# How to smooth hand boundary

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have generated edge using canny. The resulting image has rough boundary. How can I smooth it? Simple opening moprph operation doesn't work.
[image: Hand Boundary Image Link]

Answer (score 1):

You can try and trace the boundary (using, e.g., [`bwtraceboundary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwtraceboundary.html)) then fit a curve to the boundary points (using e.g., [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html)) choosing the degree of the polynom can help you achive the proper smoothing

Comment: Good solution. Alternatively,  this can be done by Eliptic Fourier Transform. It may be work better as shape descriptor.